# php pdo code to search array of column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Data present in database column are like below..

**animationno** = 300,301

**animationdate**  =  300 - 23-03-2015,   301- 23-04-2015

When user search 300 then it display **output 300-23-03-2015** from animationdate

When user search 301 then it display **output 301-23-04-2015** from animationdate.

**I have no idea is this possible..or not...and if yes...i really no guesses how to achieve this...thanks for any help...to find solution**

plz help to get solution for this..array search

```
<?php
$database= new PDO( "connection string goes here" );
$q = $_GET['q'];

$query=$database->prepare("SELECT animationdate FROM animationmaster WHERE animationno = :animationno");
$query->bindParam(':animationno', $q);
$query->execute();

$result = $query -> fetch();
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: This is not clear, what do you want to do. Construct a string with the record id and the date ? You just have to concatenate the different parts of the result...

Comment: sir i need is when i enter 300 and click search then it get only  300-23-03-2015 not all  300 - 23-03-2015, 301- 23-04-2015..plz help to implement how to do this i really have no idea....

Comment: PLEASE stop asking the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT animationdate FROM animationmaster 
WHERE animationno like '300%'
```

or

```
    $database= new PDO( "connection string goes here" );
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    $param = "'".$q."%'";

    $query=$database->prepare("SELECT animationdate FROM animationmaster WHERE animationno = :animationno");
    $query->bindParam(':animationno', $param);

$query->execute();
```

Comment: but this not return result like i want ...i want below scenarion...when user enter 300 and click search then it get only  300-23-03-2015 not all  300 - 23-03-2015, 301- 23-04-2015.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query= $database->prepare("
            SELECT animationdate
            FROM animationmaster
            WHERE animationno IN (:animationno)
        ");
```